# How to force reload of json on tomcat

Tags: json, eclipse, tomcat

I'm doing a sample website for a project. In a page, the users set some parameters to start a search on a database. The results gets stored on a JSON. So far, so good.

I need to read those results on another page: I'm basically reading and showing the contents of the JSON. Obviously, different parameters make different queries on the database, so results may vary.

The issue is that, when showing results, a previous version on the JSON pops up. I thought it was due to browser caching but i'm not so sure about it (i've checked it with firebug, the http request for the JSON comes with status 200, so it should be fine).

I'm using eclipse and I'm running on a local tomcat v7 server. I noticed that, when I open the JSON file inside my eclipse project, it gets refreshed on the website too. My guess is that the correct JSON doesn't get on the server until eclipse says so; I'd need a solution to that.

I've read somewhere that I should set the propertu "autodeploy" of my tomcat server to "true", but it already was like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is your only problem, but a 200 response status does not mean that you have avoided browser cache: in fact, the response code gets cached too. Instead, if you are using chrome net inspector, you can check if the size column says `(from cache)`. 
To be safe, you could append a timestamp to the querystring.

EDIT: I'm adding the reason why I'm not sure if this is your only problem. The point is that my answer has nothing to do with the title of the question. Your issue could really be that a json file is not reloaded. If I got it correctly, the file is a result of some user input, and I feel that it would be better to store it in some db or some key-value store

Comment: tried to check, but it seems it's charging  it from the server. Also tried the option "disable cache" with no avail. I'll try to store the data differently, I think.